Figma Component Not found issue
Issue:
I am working on a project that fetches components from Figma using Flask and the Figma API. However, when I try to retrieve the components, I get an empty list or "Component not found" response, even though I have created components in Figma.
Additional Information:
My components are located under the "Drafts" section in Figma.
I’ve checked the access token and it’s valid.
I can see the Figma file and components when I open the file in Figma, but they are not being retrieved by the API.
Question:
How can I ensure that the components in my Figma file are properly retrieved via the Figma API? Are there any specific settings or permissions I need to adjust?
I tried this method
Postman Setup:
Method: POST
URL: http://127.0.0.1:5000/generate
Headers:
Content-Type: application/json
Body (raw JSON):
{
"component_name": "Primary Button"
}
Error/Response:
I receive a successful API status response with status: 200, but the components array is always empty:
{
"error": false,
"status": 200,
"meta": {
"components": []
}
}

Since your components are in the drafts, make sure the access token you're using has permission to access files in that section.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
